# how can I select data in a table with some of them added (not sum of all)..?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table of the following structure.

[image]

So the above table stores the calories consumed by every user with his username and time at which the data was saved.

The data in the table is as follows,

[image]

Now this is how I would like to fetch the data..

I want to **select the calories, but calories with *same* date should be added**. i.e, here when i select, the fetched records should be 1200,1000.

Is it possible to accomplish in a mysql query...?? If yes, please show me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
select user_name, date(`date`) as MyDate, sum(calorie) as TotalPerDay from table
group by user_name, MyDate
```

[Example](http://sqlize.com/uFH0ozNZbx)

Take into account the id will be removed because you'll be adding many ids, so it wouldn't have any sense to display it.

Now, assuming you literally wanted this:

> I want to select the calories, but calories with same date should be added. i.e, here when i select, the fetched records should be 1200,1000.

You're looking for this (but doesn't seem to be very useful):

```
select sum(calorie) as TotalPerDay from t1
group by user_name, date(`date`)
```

[Example](http://sqlize.com/4k5Z5vP2n0)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT `ID`, `UserName`, `date`, SUM(`calorie`) as `calories`
FROM tableName
GROUP BY UserName, date(`date`)
```